# PhpMyAdmin not handling trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I currently have:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER blog_creator AFTER INSERT ON news

IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM news WHERE headline = 'LastItem' 
THEN 
INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (500, 'Hi', 'An item was posted!');

delimiter ;
```

Phpmyadmin isn't picking this up. No error message, just a loading symbol then nothing. SHOW TRIGGERS shows nothing, and inserting into news also doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing few things. 
Try this:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER blog_creator AFTER INSERT ON news
FOR EACH ROW --always add this line
BEGIN -- start code block
    -- I think it would be faster to do the count instead of exists
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE headline = 'LastItem' ) > 0) 
    THEN 
    INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (500, 'Hi', 'An item was posted!');
    END IF; --you need to end if
END// --you need to end trigger using the new delimiter

delimiter ;
```

You can try out SQLFiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/524b4/1

Comment: For some reason, phpmyadmin shows that it's loading, then does nothing. No confirmation, or error message. Other SQL queries work fine. Thanks for trying so far though.

Comment: This code should really work. I had some trouble in the past with stored procedures and triggers in phpMyAdmin. My solution was to switch to MySQL Workbench :)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?